# No sound ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, sound

I always had problem with sound since 16.04
This what i done today

```
[sudo] password for somlak: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libappindicator1 libindicator7 linux-sound-base
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
alsa-base* ubuntu-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
After this operation, 523 kB disk space will be freed.
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 170159 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.417.3) ...
Removing alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
(Reading database ... 170113 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
somlak@somlak-Inspiron-5567:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libappindicator1 libindicator7 libpulsedsp libsbc1
libwebrtc-audio-processing1 linux-sound-base pulseaudio-utils rtkit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
libcanberra-pulse* pulseaudio* pulseaudio-module-bluetooth*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
After this operation, 4,469 kB disk space will be freed.
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 170107 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing libcanberra-pulse:amd64 (0.30-5ubuntu1) ...
Removing pulseaudio-module-bluetooth (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Removing pulseaudio (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
(Reading database ... 169916 files and directories currently installed.)
Purging configuration files for pulseaudio (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
somlak@somlak-Inspiron-5567:~$ 
somlak@somlak-Inspiron-5567:~$ sudo apt-get install alsa-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libappindicator1 libindicator7 libpulsedsp libsbc1
libwebrtc-audio-processing1 pulseaudio-utils rtkit
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
apmd alsa-oss oss-compat
The following NEW packages will be installed:
alsa-base
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 145 kB of archives.
After this operation, 475 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 alsa-base all 1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5 [145 kB]
Fetched 145 kB in 2s (72.3 kB/s)    
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Selecting previously unselected package alsa-base.
(Reading database ... 169912 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../alsa-base_1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5_all.deb ...
Unpacking alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
somlak@somlak-Inspiron-5567:~$ sudo apt-get install pulseaudio
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
libappindicator1 libindicator7 libsbc1
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
pavumeter pavucontrol paman paprefs
The following NEW packages will be installed:
pulseaudio
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
Need to get 785 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,104 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://lk.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 pulseaudio amd64 1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2 [785 kB]
Fetched 785 kB in 3s (239 kB/s)     
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
Selecting previously unselected package pulseaudio.
(Reading database ... 169961 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../pulseaudio_1%3a11.1-1ubuntu7.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking pulseaudio (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Setting up pulseaudio (1:11.1-1ubuntu7.2) ...
Adding user pulse to group audio
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.2-1ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.2' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.4' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
somlak@somlak-Inspiron-5567:~$ sudo alsa force-reload
Unloading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-skl snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-hda-ext-core snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer (failed: modules still loaded: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-timer).
Loading ALSA sound driver modules: snd-hda-codec-hdmi snd-soc-skl snd-soc-hdac-hda snd-hda-ext-core snd-hda-codec-realtek snd-hda-codec-generic snd-soc-skl-ipc snd-soc-sst-ipc snd-soc-sst-dsp snd-soc-acpi-intel-match snd-soc-acpi snd-soc-core snd-compress snd-pcm-dmaengine snd-hda-intel snd-hda-codec snd-hda-core snd-hwdep snd-pcm snd-seq-midi snd-seq-midi-event snd-rawmidi snd-seq snd-seq-device snd-timer.
somlak@somlak-Inspiron-5567:~$
```

sorry I very don't know ,How to do the code in here

Comment: Welcome to ask Ubuntu! Just copy-pasting terminal output is a bad idea. Please make an effort  to ensure proper formatting of your question.

Comment: No worries. If you review my edit I just needed to insert three ` (back ticks) at the top and bottom of your code block.

Comment: You are missing the most important line; what was typed before you entered Sudo password?

Comment: I entered  somlak@somlak-Inspiron-5567:~$ sudo apt-get remove --purge alsa-base

Comment: `N: Ignoring file 'dropbox.list.save.1' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension` remove the files under `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` apt is complaining.

Comment: You've failed to tell us exactly what are your problems with sound. No sound - low sound, etc? Sorry, but I'm not psychic.

Comment: I use Ubuntu 18.04 just got new HDD , try to watching YouTube and i fine out the sound is not working .I check on Alsamixer it fine. just don't know how to make it work.

Comment: What machine are you using? Before your new HDD was sound working? If you go to Settings->Sound, what is shown listed?

Comment: I use Dell , before i use new HDD i got same problem sometime it working sometime it not working. when i go to Settings >Sound, it show Output volume, Device for sound output Headphones and Speakers built in audio and setting for selected device.

Comment: So it recognizes your output devices. Run this command `speaker-test -c2 -t wav`listening theough headphones then for speakers too. Any sound?

Comment: I has no headphone never use them at all, I can't. but for speaker i did not hear anything.

Comment: So why is *Sound Settings* showing headphones as a device? To get to the bottom of this it would require numerous tests. Looking at hardware I need to see output of `sudo lspci -nnk|grep -i -A2 audio`. Also run `aplay -l`, when nothing is being played, and run it again when you are playing something (eg like that speaker test). Post all this into question.